# Dynamic variables in objects

Tags: c#, string

Lets say that I have a string that is mostly complete. In the middle of it is an entry that is variable - for example:

`string speech = @"I am very"`*variable*`"and I need some lighter clothes"`

Assuming I don't want to create another string to handle that last part of that sentence, how do I place one of many words for "hot" in place of *variable*?

My pseudo theory would go something like this:

```
string speech = @"I am very " + &antonym + " and I need some lighter clothes";
public string putTheSentenceTogether(string antonym)
{
    return speech(antonym);
}
```

Can this be done in C#? Or an any other way that doesn't require me to split `speech` up?

Comment: Have you tried it? There are many ways to concatenate a string in c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using C# 6.0 or later, try:

```
string myAntonym = "hot";
string speech = $"I am very {myAntonym} and I need some lighter clothes";
```

Comment: Although all of these examples work, this is the cleanest and shortest, I think, therefore I'm selecting it as the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 4):

How about you do

```
string speech = @"I am very {0} and I need some lighter clothes";
public string PutTheSentenceTogether(string antonym)
{
    return string.Format(speech, antonym);
}
```

Or you can do (in C# 6.0 i.e. VS 2015 and later)

```
public string PutTheSentenceTogether(string antonym)
{
    return $"I am very {antonym} and I need some lighter clothes";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work using string interpolation:

```
public string putTheSentenceTogether(string antonym)
{
    return $"I am very {antonym} and I need some lighter clothes";
}
```

Or using `string.Format`

```
public string putTheSentenceTogether(string antonym)
{
    return string.Format("I am very {0} and I need some lighter clothes", antonym);
}
```

Provided you want to declare the string outside of the method, you could do

```
string speech = "I am very {0} and I need some lighter clothes";

public string putTheSentenceTogether(string antonym)
{
    return string.Format(speech, antonym);
}
```

Comment: Interpolation in the first example needs to have a '$' symbol in place of the '@' symbol.